# Jquery, register a function for every ajax call independently

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I want a function to be triggered on every ajax request is sent from a document, and another function to trigger when that request is completed.

This code is to be independent with the code which triggers the ajax request.

I remember it can be done in prototypeJS easily, but I haven't done this in jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success: yourmethod
});
```

> For details on the settings available for $.ajaxSetup(), see [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Comment: I would use these .ajaxStart( handler() ) and .ajaxComplete(). Thanks