# Call a function everytime and AJAX request is processed and returned from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a application where there are numerous number of ajax calls to the server.

Now I want to audit the response that comes from the server (This requirement poped up after the ajax code was laid).

So I have a function that would audit the response data, only problem is how can I get the data to be sent to the function which now sits separately.

I don't want to do the laborious work of adding the line of code for calling the function in each ajax call.

Is there easier and general way out. Somehow I could detect when a response come back and then process the response.

Using both traditional javascript method as well as `jquery` ajax calls in the system. (The app has been getting changes from a long time and has changed hands a lot so the new things get added and the older ones never get removed)

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/, http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ and http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery, register a function for every ajax call independently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901871/jquery-register-a-function-for-every-ajax-call-independently)

Comment: I sympathize with your code rot situation. Too many times, we, as developers, must work with messy code from other developers but also forget that we are the next past developer.  I encourage you, however busy you are, to clean this code up!  I will take far less time to fix the code then to maintain this mess with another obscure, catch-all fix.

Comment: @Stefan ajax prefilter doesn't go with the question as I need the function to be handled after the ajax function gets the response. The ajaxcomplete function is something I know but then the handles still need to be declared independently which is similar to adding a line of code in each ajax call... Is there a better way

Comment: @netedavisolds its not like that I never thought about but the thing is its a big mess that has few more sub messes attached to it...so by and with the time we have to get the mess cleaned up we could roll out a new cleaner version of it.. but till then its a program thats live and the patch work needs to be done for now

Comment: You should have a look at the link I posted as duplicate... this question was asked before. Btw, `ajaxComplete` would also work, have a look at the documentation again, you only have to set it up *once*.

Comment: @FelixKling I had been to that question before putting this question here but my problem is I have some code that exists in the individual `ajax` `success` section, putting a global method via `ajaxSetup` would overwrite all the code that is actually there in individual `ajax success`.

Comment: Also @FelixKling does this work with the traditional javascript ajax calls.

Comment: This only works for Ajax calls made through jQuery. If you use `XMLHttpRequest` directly there is no other way than adjusting the callbacks. Regarding `ajaxSetup`: If none of your callbacks use the `complete` callback, you can use this callback. In any case, it won't override any calls, it sets the *default* callback in case none is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your ajax calls with a helper function and use it throughout your code.

An (untested) example:

```
MyApp = MyApp || {
    logRequest: function _logRequest(settings, response) {
        // Log your response
    },

    ajax: function _ajax (settings) {
        var that = this;

        // Log attempt request here?      

        // Example of logging the success callback (do similar for error or complete)
        if (settings.success) {
            // A success handler is already specified
            settings.success = function (data) {
                that.logRequest(settings, data); // Log the response
                settings.success(data);  // Call the original complete handler                
            };
        } else {
            // No success handler is specified
            settings.success = function (data) {
                that.logRequest(settings, data);
            };
        }

        return jQuery.ajax(settings);
    }
};
```

I favour this mechanism for lots situations where I want to reduce boilerplate. I only have to modify the state of the MyApp object which is my own (named appropriately for the application), so it is sort of an interface that allows you to intercept function calls without modifying other global objects. You can also swap this functionality out with something else very easily without having to update your references everywhere, which could be useful in a lot of other situations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) should be enough to catch the `onComplete` event for all AJAX requests made through jQuery. Isn´t that what you´re asking for?

```
$('.ajaxRequest').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON(
        '/echo/json/',
        this.id,
        function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
    );
});

// Listen to all ajax requests
$("#log").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    console.log(event, request, settings);
});​
```

View **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77J4Z/)**.

Comment: does this work with the traditional `javascript` way of calling ajax.

Comment: No, `XMLHttpRequest` will not trigger any event that I´m aware of.